# Сколько одинаковых чисел в двух массивах

Tags: java, массивы

Даны два массива. Нужно посчитать сколько чисел содержится одновременно как в первом массиве, так и во втором и вывести их в порядке возрастания.

**Примечание:** Если в первом массиве есть число (например, 1), а во втором массиве это число встречается дважды (к примеру, массив из 5 элементов: `1,2,3,4,1`), то в данном случае число 1 содержится 1 раз в обоих массивах. Если число встречается несколько раз в каждом массиве, то это всё равно одно совпадение.

**Мой код:**

```
package shestnadcat;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shestnadcat2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите количество элементов первого массива");
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int i;
        int[] a = new int[b];
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            System.out.println("Введите элемент " + i);
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Введите количество элементов второго массива");
        int d = in.nextInt();
        int[] c = new int[d];
        for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
            System.out.println("Введите элемент " + i);
            c[i] = in.nextInt();   
        }
        int k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            int g = a[i];
            for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
                if (g == c[i]) {
                    k = +1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Счётчик неправильно выводит результат.

Не могу продумать вывод этих чисел.

Comment: `Счётчик неправильно выводит результат.` - и какой же?

Comment: У вас в двух циклах идет счетчик `i` а должен быть разный....стандарт `i` и `j`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский результат не изменился. Скриншот прикреплю к самому посту

Comment: @АлексейШиманский прикрепил

Comment: В массивах `{1, 1, 1}` и `{1, 1, 1}` сколько одинаковых чисел?

Comment: В случае если числа не повторяются в рамках одного массива, то во-первых: во втором цикле замените `i` на другое имя счетчика, во-вторых: увеличение счетчика надо писать `k +=1;` либо `k++;`  а то у вас он всегда единице равен будет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский переменную заменил,но вот дважды единицу он считает за 2 числа,т.е. если числа повторяются,то он всё равно засчитывает.Как исправить?

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров пфф.. зависит от того, какой результат ожидается.... вас еще andy.37 спросил об этом. Не зная, какой результат вы ожидаете никто вам не скажет, как исправить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский было в условии задачи всё сказано.

Comment: Ну это не поясняет ничего...

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров вам нужно в вопросе чётко указать, могут ли быть в рамках одного массива повторяющиеся числа, и если могут, то как их обрабатывать.

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров а если в каждом массиве `1` встречается дважды, то это всё же 2 разных совпадения?

Comment: @Regent нет,это 1 совпадение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] firstArray = readArray(in, "первого");
    int[] secondArray = readArray(in, "второго");
    //создание массива отметок о найденных совпадениях во втором массиве
    boolean[] secondMatches = new boolean[secondArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < secondMatches.length; i++)
    {
        secondMatches[i] = false;
    }
    int matchesCount = 0;
    //поиск совпадений
    for (int firstElement : firstArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (firstElement == secondArray[i])
            {
                if (!secondMatches[i])
                {
                    secondMatches[i] = true;
                    matchesCount++;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //создание массива совпадений
    int[] matches = new int[matchesCount];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (secondMatches[i])
        {
            matches[k++] = secondArray[i];
        }
    }
    //сортировка пузырьком массива совпадений
    for (int i = matches.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (matches[j] > matches[j + 1])
            {
                int swap = matches[j];
                matches[j] = matches[j + 1];
                matches[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(matchesCount);
    for (int element : matches)
    {
        System.out.print(element + " ");
    }
}

private static int[] readArray(Scanner in, String arrayNumberName)
{
    System.out.println("Введите количество элементов " + arrayNumberName + " массива");
    int elementsCount = in.nextInt();
    int[] elements = new int[elementsCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Введите элемент " + i);
        elements[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Прекрасно!) Спасибо!)

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров на здоровье. И, кстати, постарайтесь в будущем использовать  осмысленные имена переменных и не экономить на пробелах. Это весьма помогает в программировании.

Answer (score 2):

Надо засунуть все значения в `HashMap` и сравнить размер `HashMap` с количеством записей в обоих массивах:

```
int[] firstArray = new int[]{1, 3, 4, 5, 56, 6};
int[] secondArray = new int[]{11, 8, 3, 4, 5, 56, 6};
HashMap hashmap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(int i=0; i < firstArray.length; i++)
   hashmap.put(new Integer(firstArray[i]).toString(), new Integer(firstArray[i]));
for(int i=0; i < secondArray.length; i++)
   hashmap.put(new Integer(secondArray[i]).toString(), new Integer(secondArray[i]));

System.out.println("Совпадающих значений="+(firstArray.length+secondArray.length)-hashmap.size()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> first  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> second = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    first.add(1);
    first.add(2);
    first.add(3);
    first.add(42);

    second.add(3); 
    second.add(4); 
    second.add(5);
    second.add(42);

    second.retainAll(first);
    Collections.sort(second);

    System.out.println(second);
  }
}
```

[Наглядно посмотреть](https://repl.it/ExDZ).

Comment: не не не. так не пойдет. у автора примитивы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, которые возможно переделать под списки, чтобы работать как белый человек.

Comment: ничего не понял из кода...я в примитивах( можете упростить?

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров с примитивами как раз наоборот — будет мноооого кода.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не важно( главное чтобы был)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский учебные задания вряд ли подразумевают использование готовых решений. У них ведь задача научить писать нормальный код и логически и алгоритмически мыслить.

Comment: @Regent, в жизни наоборот стоит искать решения попроще.

Comment: @Other безусловно. Хоть это нигде и не сказано, но у меня стойкое ощущение, что задание всё же учебное, поэтому `retailAll` и `sort` не являются его решением. По идее, с точки зрения SO, ваш ответ является ответом на вопрос, но, сдаётся мне, автору всё нужно другое решение.

Comment: @Other кстати, если вдруг "нарисуется" условие, что при наличии в первом массиве (списке) одного элемента `3`, а во втором массиве (списке) двух элементов `3` нужно выводить `3` только один раз, то `retainAll` тут отработает не так как надо. Но это так - фантазии.

Comment: @Regent, мой пример - не решение и не пытается им быть. Решать чужие задачки, которые направлены на развитие этого кого-то - некрасиво. Искусственные ограничения, которые в природе не встретишь - это глупость.

Comment: @Regent не могли бы в примитивах написать тот же код?

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров вам нужно сначала четко сформулировать условия задачи касательно одинаковых элементов в одном массиве. Без этих условий делать что-либо бессмысленно.

Comment: @Regent дополнил условие.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант со stream api:

```
int[] firstArray = new int[]{1, 3, 4, 5, 56, 6};
int[] secondArray = new int[]{11, 8, 3, 4, 5, 56, 6};

IntStream
            .concat(Arrays.stream(firstArray), Arrays.stream(secondArray))
            .distinct()
            .sorted()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Немного заморочился и написал небольшую реализацию стримов:

```
private static class CustomIntStream {
    private final int[] array;

    public CustomIntStream(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }

    public static CustomIntStream of(int[] firstArray, int[] secondArray) {
        int[] array = new int[firstArray.length + secondArray.length];
        System.arraycopy(firstArray, 0, array, 0, firstArray.length);
        System.arraycopy(secondArray, 0, array, firstArray.length, secondArray.length);

        return new CustomIntStream(array);
    }

    public CustomIntStream distinct() {
        int[] buffer = new int[array.length];

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            boolean isContains = false;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
                if (isContains = (array[i] == array[j]))
                    break;

            if (!isContains)
                buffer[index++] = array[i];
        }

        int[] newArray = new int[index];
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newArray, 0, newArray.length);

        return new CustomIntStream(newArray);
    }

    public CustomIntStream sorted() {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
        sort(newArray, 0, newArray.length - 1);

        return new CustomIntStream(newArray);
    }

    private static void sort(int[] array, int start, int end) {

        int middle = (end - start) / 2 + start;
        int left = start;
        int right = end;

        while (left < right) {

            while (left <= end && array[middle] > array[left])
                left++;
            while (right >= start && array[middle] < array[right])
                right--;

            if (left <= right) {
                int buffer = array[left];
                array[left] = array[right];
                array[right] = buffer;
                right--;
                left++;
            }
        }

        if (start < right) sort(array, start, right);
        if (left < end) sort(array, left, end);
    }

    public void foreach(IntConsumer consumer) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            consumer.accept(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Используется аналогично:

```
CustomIntStream
            .of(firstArray, secondArray)
            .distinct()
            .sorted()
            .foreach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: хотелось бы увидеть примитивы(

Comment: шикарно) благодарю)